# What could cause -[NSPasteboard types] to crash?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nspasteboard

One of our customers is seeing a crash like this sometimes when pasting:

```
0 com.apple.Foundation 0x9143bd1d readPointerAt + 9
1 com.apple.Foundation 0x9153221f empty + 43
2 com.apple.Foundation 0x9145d41f dealloc + 21
3 com.apple.Foundation 0x9145d3ce -[NSConcreteMapTable dealloc] + 35
4 com.apple.AppKit 0x9092aa5d -[_NSPasteboardOwnersCollection dealloc] + 45
5 com.apple.AppKit 0x905cdb8f _NSPasteboardReportChangedOwner + 66
6 com.apple.AppKit 0x905cd4aa -[NSPasteboard _updateTypeCacheIfNeeded] + 51
7 com.apple.AppKit 0x905cd361 -[NSPasteboard _typesAtIndex:usesPboardTypes:] + 52
8 com.apple.AppKit 0x905cd327 -[NSPasteboard types] + 50
```

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this?

- The pasteboard object is valid as far as I can tell but then crashes internally.
- I think this is generally when pasting from another app, is it possible the other app is mismanaging its ownership of the pasteboard?

Further information from [Does NSPasteboard retain owner objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920952/does-nspasteboard-retain-owner-objects) says that yes, the pasteboard retains the owners passed to it. Therefore, this crash must be either:

- An over-release in my code. This causes an object to be deallocated while the pasteboard still holds a reference to it. I think this unlikely as you'd expect the problem to show up independent of the pasteboard, and I've not seen a single crash (report) to suggest that.
- Something in the way `NSPasteboard` manages cross-application pastes is going wrong and crashing. Anyone encountered something like that or know what could cause it?

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be when disposing of information about the previous owner (before the current owner as set by the user's most recent copy). Perhaps that's you? Check your copying code.

Also run your app under the Zombies instrument, if you haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

If you accept a drop from a dragging paste and do the actual work asynchronously in another thread, you should retain the pasteboard itself, or otherwise, it might be deallocated when the function in the main thread returns.

It can probably happen in the dragging source side.

For example:

```
- (BOOL) outlineView:(NSOutlineView*)inOutlineView acceptDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)inInfo item:(id)inItem childIndex:(NSInteger)inIndex
{
    NSPasteboard* pboard = [[inInfo draggingPasteboard] retain]; // This is necessary!

    BOOL result = YES;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^() 
    {
        // Do the real work hear:

        NSLog(@"types = %@", [pboard types]);

        [pboard release];
    });

    return result;
```

}

Comment: The retain in your example is not necessary; the block will retain the pasteboard for you anyway. And no, this is not the problem I'm seeing a few reports of.

Comment: The block retains the pasteboard only if you use it inside the block. You may use one of its pasteboard items which has only a weak reference to the pasteboard. For me, it solved frequent crashes.